# Unknown Android notification bar icon- what is this icon?

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 on AT&T USA with the below icon in the notification bar.  Any ideas on what it is?  I did a 'similar image' Google Image search and a tineye.com search to no avail.  Thanks in advance!

Icon can be seen here: http://prntscr.com/3pt9pp

Comment: Not a programming question-  it belongs on android.stackexchange.com, not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a symbol used for NFC i.e. Near Field Communication means data transfer between two NFC enabled devices by touching their NFC areas.The NFC region is centered at the symbol

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and helpful reply!  The icon's been bugging me for weeks.  :P  I'm going to leave it on for the time being as I'd like to try out the NFC check-out counters.

Answer (score 0):

That's the symbol for NFC. 
Turn it off in Settings.